# How to create composed foreign key in Fluent Migrator

Tags: fluent-migrator

I need to create a foreign key like the code below:

```
Create.ForeignKey().FromTable("TCGDocFiscalOpMedItem").ForeignColumn("IDCabecalhoDocFiscal","NumeroItem").ToTable("TCGDocFiscalItem").PrimaryColumn("IDCabecalhoDocFiscal","NumeroItem");
```

Obviously this code does not work.
How can I do something like these?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer, simply use ForeignColumns() with S at the end instead ForeignColumn().

thanks guys